# How can I set option value selected in v-select in vue.js 2?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jquery-select2, vue-select, v-select

I am trying to set `option` `selected` where `option` value is `1`. But I am getting in trouble when using `v-select` from vuejs. This is how I am trying to do -

```
<v-select name="branchid" v-model="branchid" 
         :options="branches.map(branches => ({label: branches.label, value: branches.value}))" 
         :selected="branches.value === 1"></v-select>
```

Would someone help me please to get the `option` value `selected` when `option` value is `1`?

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a simplified version of what (I think) you're trying to do:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <select v-on:change="select($event);" value="branchid">
        <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
        <option :selected="branchid === 1">1</option>
        <option :selected="branchid === 2">2</option>
        <option :selected="branchid === 3">3</option>
      </select>
      <span>Selected: {{ branchid }}</span>
      <button v-on:click="selectOne">Select Option 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      branchid: 0,
      branchidTwo: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    select: function(evt) {
    this.branchid = evt.target.value;
  },
    selectOne: function() {
      this.branchid = 1;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This does not use the v-model pattern. The docs explicitly state that if you use v-model, the class itself will be used as the source of truth rather than value or selected. You'll see I've added a button that will set the selected option on the select component.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, I need the search option to choose the `option` value

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve here? What do you mean by "search option"?

Comment: I have a branch list, during transfer my products to stock warehouse a branch also be selected and I want to keep "warehouse" (it also a branch and it's id is1)  te is selected for all time. But, if a user wants to select another branch from the branch list except for the warehouse branch then, during selection user will be able to select with search filter (like select2). In this form already I am getting branch dynamically from database in vuejs script.

Comment: data:{branches: [],
        branches: [
            @foreach($branches as $branch)
                {
                    value: '{{ $branch['branchid'] }}',
                    label: '{{ $branch['branchname'] }}',
                },
            @endforeach
        ], }

Comment: You can't have two options selected at the same time in a select though. Surely the answer is to have "warehouse" as a default selection in your class, and then have an optional second option which is selected from the dropdown?

Comment: From dropdown options only first one I mean warehouse should be the default selected and others will be with searchable option to select. (sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it with select v-model with the value you want selected

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data: {
      selected: 'A',
      options: [
        { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
        { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
        { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
      ]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

Source : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select